# How to summon an object in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I summon an object in unity?
I have a folder named Objects and there is an object I want to summon named RandomBeam and I want to summon it at -12.5, 0, 0.

-Thanks.

> Unity2D

Comment: use Instantiate method

Answer (score 1):

create variable in custom script `public GameObject RandomBeamPrefab;` (dont forget to drag and drop RandomBeam  from folder to your components field named RandomBeamPrefab)

then use this
`Instantiate(RandomBeamPrefab, new Vector3(-12.5f, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);`

[image: example here]